# Angular 2 Http Get with Authentication

Tags: angular

I'm trying to do a get call to an API. I tested with POSTMAN the call and it works fine, but when I try to use Angular 2 HTTP I get an error.

Here is the error: OPTIONS [URL] 405 (method not allowed). I'm using my test server on localhost to connect to the API on another server. The serve does have Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Here is my code.

```
    getAllAlerts(){
        let headers = new Headers({'authorization':'Bearer ACCESSTOKEN'}),
            options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

        return this.http.get(this.mentionUrl,options).map((resp) => resp.json());
    }
```

When I look on my Network (tab) on Chrome the request method is changed to OPTIONS and the status code is 405 Method Not Allowed.

Answer (score 0):

On your API, you also have to specify the methods and headers allowed.

So, for eg, when using Rails and the Rack::CORS gem, the configuration is something like:

```
# configure rails to allow CORS from all sources
    config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end
```

The above configures Rails to allow CORS requests for methods: GET, POST and OPTIONS.

The OPTIONS is necessary because of how CORS works - whenever you are doing a cross origin request, the browser first attempts an OPTIONS request and checks the response headers for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Only if the browser sees that header in  the response does it send the actual request